Distribution of $Y=-\log(X)$ when $X\sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$
I have been looking at the distribution of $Y=-\log(X)$ when $X\sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, so $Y$ is supported on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.  Might this be called a negative exp-Beta distribution?
For $\beta=1$, it is well known that $Y \sim  \operatorname{Exp}(\alpha)$ i.e. $\operatorname{Gamma}(1,\alpha)$. I am interested in cases where $\beta$ takes other values.
Empirically, for integer $\beta$, it seems $m=\mathbb E[Y] = \sum\limits_{k=\alpha}^{\alpha+\beta-1} \frac1k$ and $v=\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\sum\limits_{k=\alpha}^{\alpha+\beta-1} \frac1{k^2}$, or at least these are very close approximations.  Are these exact? What would be the equivalent for non-integer $\beta$?
Again empirically, it seems that an approximation to the distribution of $Y$ is $\operatorname{Gamma}\left(\frac{m^2}{v},\frac{m}{v}\right)$, and this seems to be a better approximation when $\alpha \not \ll \beta$.  Is there a justification for this approximation? Is there a description of the exact distribution when $\beta \not = 1$?
As an illustration, using R,
alpha <- 5.6789
beta <- 8
cases <- 10^6
X <- qbeta(ppoints(cases), alpha, beta)
Y <- -log(X)
mean(Y)
# 0.9327204
print(m <- sum(1/(alpha:(alpha+beta-1))))
# 0.9327205
var(Y)
# 0.1166561
print(v <- sum(1/(alpha:(alpha+beta-1))^2))
# 0.1166563

Looking at the density of $Y$ in black and the corresponding Gamma distribution in red shows how close they are:
plot(density(Y))
curve(dgamma(x, shape=m^2/v, rate=m/v), 
             from=0, to=max(Y), col="red", add=TRUE)



Added: Jarle Tufto has answered the first part of the question: my observed mean and variance are exact for integer $\beta$ and can be generalised for non-integer $\beta$ using the digamma and trigamma functions: $m=\mathbb E[Y] = \psi^{(0)}(\alpha+\beta) - \psi^{(0)}(\alpha)$ and $v=\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\psi^{(1)}(\alpha) - \psi^{(1)}(\alpha+\beta)$.
print(m <- digamma(alpha+beta) - digamma(alpha))
# 0.9327205
print(v <- trigamma(alpha) - trigamma(alpha+beta))
# 0.1166563

His moment generating function for $Y=-\log(X)$ of $M(t)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)\Gamma(\alpha-t)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+\beta-t)}$ when $t < \alpha$ (in black below) might be compared with the corresponding Gamma distribution's MGF of $\left(1-\frac{t}{m/v}\right)^{-m^2/v}$ for $t < \frac{m}{v}$ (in red below).   These are a close match near $t=0$ (the zeroth, first and second moments are the same in the two distributions so the curves have the same value, tangent and curvature at $t=0$):
curve(gamma(alpha+beta) * gamma(alpha-x) / 
     (gamma(alpha) * gamma(alpha+beta-x)), 
     from=-1, to=1, lwd=2)
curve((1 - x/(m/v)) ^ (-m^2/v), 
     from=-1, to=1, add=TRUE, col="red")


though they differ for large $t$ when $\beta \not = 1$ (seen below with a log scale), and indeed must differ when $\beta \not = 1$ as one has an  asymptote when $t \to \alpha$ and the other when $t \to \frac{m}{v}$.
curve(gamma(alpha+beta) * gamma(alpha-x) / 
     (gamma(alpha) * gamma(alpha+beta-x)), 
      from=-m/v*1.1, to=alpha*0.99, lwd=2, log="y", 
      xlim=c(-m/v, max(alpha,m/v)))
curve((1-x/(m/v))^(-m^2/v), 
      from=-m/v*1.1, to=(m/v)*.99, add=TRUE, col="red")


It would be nice to have a more formal way of describing the closeness of the two MGFs and their difference.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982203/pdf-of-y-logx-when-x-is-beta-distributed

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085184/how-to-compute-e-logx-when-x-follows-a-beta-distribution

The moment-generating function of $Y=-\ln X$ is by definition
\begin{align}
M(t)&=E(e^{-t\ln X})\\&=E(X^{-t})\\&=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-t-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} dx\\&=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)\Gamma(\alpha-t)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+\beta-t)}
\end{align}
and its cumulant-generating function is
$$
K(t)=\ln\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)+\ln\Gamma(\alpha - t)-\ln\Gamma(\alpha)-\ln\Gamma(\alpha+\beta - t).
$$
Thus,
$$
EY=K'(0)=\psi^{(0)}(\alpha+\beta)-\psi^{(0)}(\alpha)
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}Y=K''(0)=-\psi^{(1)}(\alpha+\beta)+\psi^{(1)}(\alpha)
$$
where $\psi^{(0)}$ and $\psi^{(1)}$ are the di- and trigamma functions.
For integer $\alpha$ and $\beta$, using this recurrence relation, it indeed follows that
$$
EY=\sum_{k=\alpha}^{\alpha+\beta-1}\frac 1k
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}Y=\sum_{k=\alpha}^{\alpha+\beta-1}\frac 1{k^2}.
$$

Did you mean $dx$ rather than $dt$?
